# I am really confused and frustrated about my php website and mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, database

So basically I've created a MYSQL database that holds information about a gaming server player information, it's loaded into this PHP website that I created just 2 days ago (I'm completely new to PHP, I only started experimenting on it 2 days ago). So I had it all fixed up but on a localhost, it could fetch the data from the mysql database but only in the localhost, today I wanted to host a free mysql hostname is: fdb3.runhosting.com  username: 1141497_damagedz and ofcourse I know the password. But when I'm trying to type this in via my PHP code in the db_connect line it gives me error saying it fails to connect at line 13 which is the line of $db_connect line, before it did work under the localhost but just now it doesnt work because I've deleted 3 files from xampp but surely that shouldnt matter now since its hosted on a whole different place like fdb3.runhosting.com  ??

Also I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver to make the PHP website, before I just had to type in

```
http://localhost/tester.php
```

to open up my tester.php website that I've been working on, but now after I deleted the xampp it wont open this so I can't really tell what I'm doing or does it work or not, this is after I deleted my xampp, which is after I deleted my 3 files from xampp. So you can see i'm really confused and I do not know how to fix this at all, I don't know why db_connect at php gives me errors when clearly my fdb3.runhosting.com mysql database works just fine... I've created tables there too. Also how may I run my tester.php file without the localhost? Please tell me I'm really confused and really need help, thank you!

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you sure the user has permissions to connect to the database. Also, check whether the user has permissions from the host you are trying to connect from.

Comment: Could you post code? Also, it may be a better idea to host the entire project on some hosting company's box, which includes a PHP and a MySQL server.

Comment: Break your paragraphs into thoughts, not monolithic blocks of text that's hard to read. Typically, most paragraphs are two to four sentences long, with relatively short sentences.

Comment: Are you trying to connect directly to the hosted database from a local PHP file?  Are you sure the host opens access to the database like that?

Comment: This is quite hard to understand. Are you saying that your PHP code running on your local machine can't connect to your remote database? If so that's pretty standard especially with cheap or free hosting. If your code is uploaded to the remote host as will it'll work. Is that what you're asking? Please edit your question including the title (which isn't much use to anyone as it stands)

Comment: @David: yes im trying to connect directly to the hosted database from a local PHP file! I'm not really sure, who do I check?

moopet: Yes thats what I mean, what do you mean its standard with cheap or free host, meaning I need to get a better host? if so also please let me know how I could possibly open the PHP file cuz i can no longer open it through localhost due to some actions I've taken on my xampp which disallows me to open files through localhost if you know what I mean

Comment: @MirwaisMaarij: It's unlikely that the host allows direct database connections from the outside world like that, unless they explicitly state that they allow it.  It's generally viewed as a significant security risk.  Chances are that they expect you to run the PHP code on their host as well.

Comment: Oh let me check that, I'll try to host the PHP too on their website then I'll get back to you on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I've deleted 3 files from xampp but surely that shouldnt matter"

Which 3 files and how do you come to that conclusion? Everything you say tends to indicate the reverse to be true!

Re-install XAMPP is the logical first option. Backup your htdocs folder then re-install. Don't know if you'll need the backup or not (I suspect not)

Comment: But what I'm saying is that the xampp is only needed if you are trying to work on things on the localhost, but for now I've moved on to a free host therefore the xampp should no longer be needed? I mean I'm fetching data from a free host not from xampp phpmyadmin anymore which was on my localhost, but yeah i've kinda forgot the names of the files but they were in the htdocs, It wouldnt let me deleted the xampp it says it's running mysql at the background, but how do I close it?

Comment: I've figured out the files that I've deleted are .htaccess, from htdocs: forbiddne, htdocs: xampp and phpmyadmin on xampp folder

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david).

It is highly unlikely you can use the remote database at `fdb3.runhosting.com` using PHP scripts on your local computer. XAMPP includes a MySQL database server and had you not deleted phpMyAdmin you would be able to use that to browse the databases on it.

Develop the website on your local XAMPP install and local XAMPP database, then export the database to the remote host and copy the files across when you are ready to view it online.

It's also worth keeping the XAMPP install folder and others because it contains information on XAMP and I believe allows you to check whether the version you're running is the latest one.